# Is possible, feasible or even recommended (if possible), to change the title or the keywords of a page using Google Tag Manager?

Tags: seo, google, ajax, google-tag-manager, crawlable-ajax

Does Google Tag Manager could or should be used to change content in a page, like title, keywords or description?

Comment: You can edit the tags, but it seems unlikely that this will affect SEO positively (it might be seen as an attempt at cloaking, in that case the effect would be negative). Unlike in earlier times Google now renders some Javascript when it crawls the page, but I doubt it'll catch metatags changed via JS. However the only definitive way would be to test this - I don't think anybody has done a "scientific" test on this yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is improving it's ability to read javascript rendered pages. However, it's not to a point you can rely on it for inserting critical headers.

Here is [one such article](http://www.simoahava.com/seo/dynamically-added-meta-data-indexed-google-crawlers/) on researching this possibility.

For now, you need to have the important information embedded into the HTML when it's served. There is also the chance that javascript rendered changes in content will be seen as [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) - although it is commonly used for A/B testing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the GTM is useful in this case. The video from Google will give you a clue where you can use the tag for: https://youtu.be/7FXbsCWsEi8 .

Comment: I see, this idea came from a client, saying that he wants a site where he can change the title and others meta tag through Tag Manager, as far as i know, even if is possible it will change things using javascript and change meta tags with javascript will impact SEO.